# Derivation of input admittance of a lossless T-Junction Power Divider that is matched at the input port

Tags: transmission-line, microwave, characteristic-impedance, power-divider

I'm trying to understand how the equation for the input admittance for a lossless T-Junction power divider was derived, which is only matched at the input.

Let \$Z_0\$, \$Z_1\$, \$Z_2\$ be the characteristics impedances of the 1st, 2nd and 3rd ports, respectively. 1st port is our input port. 2nd and 3rd ports are our output ports.(Ports 2 and 3 are not matched, only port 1 is).

[image: diagram of T-junction power divider with labelled components]

The input admittance is said to be

$$ Y_{in} = jB + \frac{1}{Z_1} + \frac{1}{Z_2}$$

Let us set \$B = 0\$ for simplicity.

$$ Y_{in} = \frac{1}{Z_1} + \frac{1}{Z_2}$$

How was the above equation derived? Why *is* the input admittance equal to the sum of inverse characteristic impedances of the transmission lines at the 2nd and 3rd ports?

In my opinion, since the two transmission lines (\$Z_1\$ and \$Z_2\$) are open-circuited, the input impedances of the two lines are respectively:
$$Z_{1, in} = -jZ_1\cot(\beta l_1)$$
and
$$Z_{2, in} = -jZ_2\cot(\beta l_2)$$

Thus the input admittance should be:
$$Y_{in} = \frac{1}{Z_{1, in}} + \frac{1}{Z_{2, in}}$$

What am I doing wrong?

Further, it makes perfect sense to me that \$Y_{in} = \frac{1}{Z_0} \$ as the input impedance for a matched transmission line with a characteristic impedance of \$Z_0\$ is: \$Z_{in} = Z_0\$

I'm following David M. Pozar's book titled "Microwave Engineering".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a more careful examination of the book, I learned that the book says "In order for the divider to be matched to the input line of characteristic impedance \$Z_0\$, we must have...(above equation)"

Which really means: \$S_{11} = 0\$. \$S_{11}\$ is defined as:
$$S_{11} = \left.\frac{b_1}{a_1}\right\vert_{a_2, a_3 = 0}$$
To achieve this the other two ports must be matched as well, to prevent any reflections from their ends. Thus we match the last two ports with their respective characteristic impedances \$Z_1\$ and \$Z_2\$ respectively.

The impedances thus seen from the junction towards the two ports are: \$Z_1\$ and \$Z_2\$ respectively (expected behaviour of load-matched transmission lines).

Since these two impedances are parallel to each other, we consider looking at the admittance \$Y_{in}\$:

$$Y_{in} = \frac{1}{Z_1} + \frac{1}{Z_2} $$

Which in turn must be equal to \$\frac{1}{Z_0}\$ to ensure that \$S_{11}\$ remains zero.